# Combining LINQ queries with entity framework C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have a linq query which selects several fields from my Customer table.

Applied to this method are multiple filters, using `Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<T>>` with `.Invoke`.

The original query is essentially `select * from customer`.

The filter method is essentially `select top 10`

The output SQL is `select top 10 from (select * from customer)`

My customer table has over 1,000,000 rows which causes this query to take about 7 seconds to execute in SSMS. If I alter the output SQL to `select top 10 from (select top 10 * from customer)` by running it in SSMS then the query is instant (as you'd expect).

I am wondering if anyone knows what might cause LINQ to not combine these in a nice way, and if there is a best practice/workaround I can implement.

I should note that my actual code isn't select * it is selecting a few fields, but there is nothing more complex.

I am using SQL Server 2008 and MVC 3 with entity framework (not sure what version)

Edit: I should add, it's IQueryable all the way, nothing is evaluated until the end, and as a result the long execution is confined to that single line.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: I cannot remember, I think I added more indexes to the database and it became a non-issue

Comment: That's cool .As long as you got something to work and perform okay, that's the main thing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it's not being optimised.

If the filter method really is equivalent to `SELECT TOP 10` then you should be able to do it like this:

```
return query.Take(10);
```

which would resolve to `select top 10 * from customer` rather than the more convoluted thing you ended up with.

If this won't work then I'm afraid I'll need a little more detail.

EDIT: To clarify, if you do this in LINQ:

```
DataItems.Take(10).Take(10)
```

you would get this SQL:

```
SELECT TOP (10) [t1].[col1], [t1].[col2]
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (10) [t0].[col1], [t0].[col2]
    FROM [DataItem] AS [t0]
    ) AS [t1]
```

So if you can somehow use a `Take(n)` you will be okay.